# fig invalid repository name error

Tags: docker, yaml, fig

It appears as if fig is using the root directory's name when it generates a repository name during "fig up". I can't figure out how to specify one in the yaml. I already have a repository name registered with docker or does repository mean docker image?

Error message attempting to "fig up":

```
  Invalid repository name (DDCIntegrationDevEnvs_es), only [a-z0-9-_.] are allowed
```

Here is my fig.yaml:

```
  nodejs:
      build: ./nodejs
      links:
          - es
          - rabbitmq
  es:
      build: ./elasticsearch
  rabbitmq:
      build: ./rabbitmq
      environment:
          PARENT_HOSTNAME:DALM0CXXFD11
```

NOTE: I tried adding FIG_PROJECT_NAME to the top of the fig.yml but received this error:

```
  Service "%s" doesn't have any configuration options. All top level keys in your fig.yml must map to a dictionary of configuration options.
```

Comment: Your best bet is lowercasing your directory to `DDCIntegrationDevEnvs_es`. If you are using git, this is possible without any errors, just change  directory to something like `ddcintegration_dev_envs_es`. That way you do not have to pass or export any variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an [open pull request](https://github.com/docker/fig/pull/568) to fix this, but it hasn't been merged yet.

The `FIG_PROJECT_NAME` variable will work, but it needs to be an environment variable. You can also pass it at the command line using the `project-name` flag.

Environment variable:

```
export FIG_PROJECT_NAME="newname"
fig up
```

Command line:

```
fig --project-name=newname up
```